# Get com port from usb

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to recover the number of the com port associated with a Zwave controller pluged using usb in Windows 10 IoT. I'm using the following code:

```
 listOfSerialDevices = new ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation>();    
 listOfSerialDevices = await _serial.ListAvailablePorts().ConfigureAwait(false);
 DeviceInformation result=null;
 if (listOfSerialDevices.Count !=0)
 {
      foreach (DeviceInformation DeviceInfo in listOfSerialDevices)
           {
            if (DeviceInfo.Name== "USB Serial Device")
                    {
                        SerialDevice PortCom =await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(DeviceInfo.Id);
                        result = DeviceInfo;
                    }
                }
            }
```

`

My problem is that I can init the SerialDevice "PortCom" but the field portname supposed to contain the good Com number remains empty...
Did somebody have the same problem? I tried on Windows 10.It worked well but not on IoT.

Comment: Is the ZWave controller using FTDI so that windows detects the device as serial port? If so, are you sure that FTDI is supported by IoT Core?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are you talking about? My device is at the moment detected as `usb serial device`. This morning I tried installing [this](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) But I still can't see any PortName in my SerialDevice

Comment: Which zwave controller do you have?

Comment: I edited my comment above, and my controller is the UZB key from sigma design

Comment: I'm not an expert, just trying to help you out. I know IoT had issues supporting FTDI devices. Just googled again and ran into this (http://embedded101.com/Blogs/David-Jones/entryid/666/win-10-iot-core-ftdi-serial-driver). Also with a screenshot how you can check if the device is recognized on your IoT device. So there seems to be a device drive for the ARM processor. Can you check if your IoT device properly recognizes the UZB key? If not, does this driver help?

Comment: That's what I tried this morning. On my raspbery's screen, I can see my uzb in my connected devices and I can Initialize a Serial communication using other method. But I have to use this one to get the com port to pass it to my Zwave layer. But I'm pretty sure my device is supported by the OS. Thx for your help!

Comment: Is it working then?

Comment: nope, I have the same issue as at the begining

Comment: I tried to connect to another device, I can see "uart0" in the PortName. So maybe it's a driver issue?

Comment: I will look into this myself soon. Currently busy with rpi and arduino for another project. When done I will pick up my zwave project. Leave the question open, and if you learn something post it here. I will do the same.

Comment: To add more informations, here are the informations I have when I look to the device in my device Portal:  

ID : USB\VID_0658&PID_0200\5&3753427A&0&5

Description : USB Serial Device

Class : Ports

Manufacturer : Microsoft

StatusCode : 25190410